# Is there a way to add text to a message with reactions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I want to try to make something that you can "type" with reactions but for some reason it won't work, instead of just adding on, it will replace the last one then go on the next, then replace that one and repeating. How do I make it work properly? I am trying to make some sort of interactive discord calculator

```
    client.on('message' , async msg => {
    if(msg.content === "mb!calculate") {
        msg.author.calculator = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('0000ff')
        .setTitle('Calculator')
        .setDescription('>> ');
       msg.author.calEmbed = await msg.channel.send(msg.author.calculator);
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('1️⃣');
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('2️⃣');
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('3️⃣');
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('4️⃣');
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('5️⃣');
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('6️⃣');
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('7️⃣');
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('8️⃣');
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('9️⃣');
        msg.author.actEmbed = msg.author.calEmbed.embeds[0];
    }
})

client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.partial) {

        try {
            await reaction.fetch();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return;
        }
    }

    if(reaction.message === user.calEmbed) {
        reaction.users.remove(user.id);
        if(reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣') {
        user.calculator.setDescription(user.actEmbed.description + '1');
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '2️⃣') {
            user.calculator.setDescription(user.actEmbed.description + '2');
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '3️⃣') {
            user.calculator.setDescription(user.actEmbed.description + '3');
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '4️⃣') {
            user.calculator.setDescription(user.actEmbed.description + '4');
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '5️⃣') {
            user.calculator.setDescription(user.actEmbed.description + '5');
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '6️⃣') {
            user.calculator.setDescription(user.actEmbed.description + '6');
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '7️⃣') {
            user.calculator.setDescription(user.actEmbed.description + '7');
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '8️⃣') {
            user.calculator.setDescription(user.actEmbed.description + '8');
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '9️⃣') {
            user.calculator.setDescription(user.actEmbed.description + '9');
        }
        user.calEmbed.edit(user.calculator);
        user.actEmbed = user.calEmbed.embeds[0];
    }
})
```

So what I am doing is I am adding the variable to a user so multiple people can use it at the same time, but not other people's. I am not finishing yet as it is doing what I said above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found what I did wrong. I didn't need the user.actEmbed actually since the changes are being done to user.calculator, which means that all I needed was to change all the things saying "actEmbed" to "calculator". Here's the edited version.

```
 client.on('message' , async msg => {
    if(msg.content === "mb!calculate") {
        msg.author.calculator = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('0000ff')
        .setTitle('Calculator')
        .setDescription('>> ');
       msg.author.calEmbed = await msg.channel.send(msg.author.calculator);
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('1️⃣');
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('2️⃣');
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('3️⃣');
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('4️⃣');
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('5️⃣');
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('6️⃣');
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('7️⃣');
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('8️⃣');
        msg.author.calEmbed.react('9️⃣');
    }
})

client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.partial) {

        try {
            await reaction.fetch();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return;
        }
    }

    if(reaction.message === user.calEmbed) {
        reaction.users.remove(user.id);
        if(reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣') {
        user.calculator.setDescription(user.calculator.description + '1');
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '2️⃣') {
            user.calculator.setDescription(user.calculator.description + '2');
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '3️⃣') {
            user.calculator.setDescription(user.calculator.description + '3');
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '4️⃣') {
            user.calculator.setDescription(user.calculator.description + '4');
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '5️⃣') {
            user.calculator.setDescription(user.calculator.description + '5');
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '6️⃣') {
            user.calculator.setDescription(user.calculator.description + '6');
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '7️⃣') {
            user.calculator.setDescription(user.calculator.description + '7');
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '8️⃣') {
            user.calculator.setDescription(user.calculator.description + '8');
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '9️⃣') {
            user.calculator.setDescription(user.calculator.description + '9');
        }
        user.calEmbed.edit(user.calculator)
       
    }
})
```